# How to get DATA from a mysql query bewtween two dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, between

I am Looking for a way to fetch the data between two date, for which I am using below query,

```
SELECT  tbl_docuserstatus.*,tbl_doc.doc_assoc_id,tbl_doctype.doctype_id,tbl_doctype.doctype_name,tbl_doc.doc_reference_number,tbl_doc.doc_date,tbl_doc.doc_start,tbl_doc.creator_id,tbl_doc.control_id,tbl_doc.company_id,tbl_doc.vendor_id,tbl_doc.amount,tbl_doc.currency,tbl_doc.paid,tbl_doc.urgent,tbl_dompany.company_name,tbl_dompany.company_code,tbl_vendor.vendor_name 
                FROM
                     tbl_docuserstatus
                LEFT JOIN
                    tbl_doc ON tbl_doc.doc_id = tbl_docuserstatus.doc_id
                LEFT JOIN
                    tbl_doctype ON tbl_doctype.doctype_id = tbl_doc.doctype_id
                LEFT JOIN
                    tbl_company ON tbl_company.company_id =  tbl_doc.company_id 
                LEFT JOIN 
                    tbl_vendor ON tbl_vendor.vendor_id = tbl_doc.vendor_id
                LEFT JOIN 
                    tbl_users ON tbl_users.user_id = tbl_doc.creator_id 
                WHERE
                     payment_status = '0' AND tbl_doc.company_id='1' AND  AND tbl_doc.doctype_id = '1' AND tbl_doc.doc_date BETWEEN '2011-04-05 00:00:00' AND '2011-04-07 00:00:00'
```

here the above query given me syntax error, so could some one tell me,

How to get DATA from a mysql query bewtween two dates?

Comment: @Rodin- #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND tbl_doc.doctype_id = '1' AND tbl_doc.doc_date BETWEEN '2011-04-05 00:00:00' ' at line 15

Comment: not sure if this is the syntax error or just a copy/paste issue but you have 2 consecutive `AND` statements in `AND tbl_doc.company_id='1' AND  AND tbl_doc.doctype_id = '1'`

Comment: `...tbl_doc.company_id='1' AND  AND tbl_doc.doctype_id = '1'...` <-- Double AND keyword, probably gives the error.

Comment: True!! Rectified It Thanx Any Ways, I didnt noticed the Double End...It was a Human printing mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this additional `AND` from you query

```
payment_status = '0' AND tbl_doc.company_id='1' AND  AND tbl_doc.doctype_id = '1' AND
```

To

```
payment_status = '0' AND tbl_doc.company_id='1' AND tbl_doc.doctype_id = '1' AND
```